# Sql join tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table as A,B .Table A holds my category names and table B holds
my fk_tbl_A ,time ,machine name.

I want to calculate the time ,which I have used for each machine and grouped by fk_abl_A
I wrote the below code in SQL 2012:

```
select sum(cast(a.during_time as int))
from dbo.sabt_bazdid as a join
     dbo.ability as b
     on a.fk_operator_ability = b.id
Group by a.fk_operator_ability
```

The code working well here but when I want to show the names of the category in table A ,
Sql shows error.

```
select b.name, sum(cast(a.during_time as int))
from dbo.sabt_bazdid as a join
     dbo.ability as b
     on a.fk_operator_ability = b.id
Group by a.fk_operator_ability
```

Please help me to solve problem
Thanks.

Comment: name is not included in `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b.name` is not in the `group by` clause.  You need to put it there or put it in an aggregation function:

```
select b.name, sum(cast(a.during_time as int))
from dbo.sabt_bazdid as a join
     dbo.ability as b
     on a.fk_operator_ability = b.id
Group by b.name, a.fk_operator_ability;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the b.name in the group by clause or in the aggregation function. just put the  b.name attribute in the group by clause.

```
select b.name,sum(cast(a.during_time as int))
from dbo.sabt_bazdid as a join
     dbo.ability as b
     on a.fk_operator_ability = b.id
Group by a.fk_operator_ability ,b.name
```

This is run the query.